# BASH getopts more arguments after option

Tags: bash

how can I make getopts take 2 arguments after -h option? I mean it is supposed to be saved in array but either it doesn't work, or I am making mistake by writing it down like this: echo " ${array[1]}  ${array[2]}"

```
 OPTIND=1 
    hh=
    while getopts "h:" flag
    do
    case "$flag" in
    h)
    hh=($OPTARG)  ;;
   esac
   done
   shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. What you can do is to pass the two arguments quoted and separated by an appropriate delimiter and split `OPTARG` to obtain the two parts.

Examples of possible calling syntaxes are:

```
prog -h part1:part2

prog -h "part1 part2"
```

And in your `case` statement you can split the components by, e.g. in case of a colon delimiter:

```
p1=${OPTARG%:*} p2=${OPTARG#*:}
```

Edit (to clarify): An "appropriate delimiter" is one that is not part of the individual `part1`/`part2` components (thus unique in the composite `OPTARG`), so that the splitting is unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to pass `-h` several times:

```
OPTIND=1 
hh=()
while getopts h: flag; do
  case "$flag" in
    h) hh+=("$OPTARG");;
  esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
```

And call it as:

```
myscript -h host1 -h host2...
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `getopts` is not intended to be used like this.

Long answer: you could try something like this (untested), but `getopts` won't be able to do syntax checking:

```
OPTIND=1 
hh=()
args=( "$@" )
while getopts "h:" flag; do
  case "$flag" in
  h)
    hh=("$OPTARG" "${args[$OPTIND]}")
    $((OPTIND++))
    ;;
  esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
```

If you go down this path, you'd need to add your own error handling for e.g. the 2nd arg doesn't exist/is empty/looks like an option instead of an argument.